# OpenSSLX509Certificate TimeoutException

Tags: android, openssl, java-security, google-conscrypt

I am seeing following crash in an Android app and don't have a clue where this can happen since the stacktrace does not point it to me clearly. Do somebody of you have a clue, idea, hint how this can happen?

TimeoutException (@com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto:X509_free:-2) via (@com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate:finalize:491) FULL TRACE: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.X509_free(Native Method) at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.finalize(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:491) at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187) at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

TimeoutException (@java.lang.Object:finalize:224) via (@com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate:finalize:494) FULL TRACE: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds at java.lang.Object.finalize(Object.java:224) at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.finalize(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:494) at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187) at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

TimeoutException (@java.lang.Object:wait:-2) via (@java.lang.Object:wait:401) FULL TRACE: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401) at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102) at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73) at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Answer (score 0):

This same crash is also reported in Github but still no one has any solutions on it:
[link](https://github.com/google/conscrypt/issues/378)

Seems like Google devs still investigating the root cause.